# How to Store non-serialized object into rediscache using kryoSerialzation

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, jedis, kryo

I'm using redis cache on my spring boot application and i need to store an unknown type of response object into redisTemplate. so i'm using kryoSerialzation on my redisTemplates,

> Exception :

```
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.io.NotSerializableException: class sample.data.redis.model.Student not serializable
at org.objenesis.strategy.SerializingInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(SerializingInstantiatorStrategy.java:58)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstantiator(Kryo.java:1127)
at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.newInstance(Kryo.java:1136)
```

> Note:

*I couldn't implements Serializable interface on my response object, since its dynamic and unknown type on my application*

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
         <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.esotericsoftware</groupId>
        <artifactId>kryo</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

### *KryoRedisSerializer.java*

```
    public class KryoRedisSerializer implements RedisSerializer<Object>{

    private  final ThreadLocal<Kryo> kryoThreadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Kryo>() {
         @Override
         protected Kryo initialValue() {
             Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
             kryo.register(Object.class);
             return kryo;
         }
     };
     public KryoRedisSerializer() {
         kryoThreadLocal.get().setInstantiatorStrategy((InstantiatorStrategy) new SerializingInstantiatorStrategy());
       }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(Object object) throws SerializationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         if (object == null) {
             return new byte[0];
          }

          try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
             Output output = new Output(outputStream);
             kryoThreadLocal.get().writeClassAndObject(output, object);
             return output.toBytes();
          } catch (IOException e) {
             throw new SerializationException("Failed Serialization", e);
          }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws SerializationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (bytes == null || bytes.length == 0) {
             return null;
          }
          try (Input input = new Input(bytes)) {
             return kryoThreadLocal.get().readClassAndObject(input);
          }
      }
    }
}
```

### *SpringRadisConfig.java*

```
 @Configuration
public class SpringRadisConfig {
    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHostName("localhost");
        connectionFactory.setPort(6379);
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {

        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());

        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());

        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(kryoRedisSSerializer());
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(new JdkSerializationRedisSerializer());

        redisTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

        return redisTemplate;
    }
    @Bean
    public RedisSerializer<Object> kryoRedisSSerializer() {
       return new KryoRedisSSerializer();
    }
}
```

*SampleRedisApplication.java (main method)*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "sample.data.redis")
public class SampleRedisApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private SpringRadisConfig redisConfig;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {/*
        ValueOperations<String, String> ops = this.template.opsForValue();
        String key = "spring.boot.redis.test";
        if (!this.template.hasKey(key)) {
            ops.set(key, "Hi Ratheesh ");
        }
        System.out.println("Found key " + key + ", value=" + ops.get(key));*/

        RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = redisConfig.redisTemplate();
        ValueOperations<String, Object> values = redisTemplate.opsForValue();

        try { 
            Student student = new Student(1L, "Vishal");
            values.set("student", student);
            Student std = (Student) values.get("student");

            System.out.println(std.getId());
            System.out.println(std.getName());

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Close the context so it doesn't stay awake listening for redis
        SpringApplication.run(SampleRedisApplication.class, args).close();
    }

}
```

Assume student is the response object which i'm getting from remote API, actually i don't have any model object definition(POJO) on my application for API response, because my API response type is (Type T) ie dynamic nodes

I found a solution in [github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/issues/213) but that is not working (convert object to array and store it Redis)

Answer (score 1):

**Later i decided to use Redisson instead of Jedis client, that could resolve my serialization issue**

CacheManager Config for cachable/cachPut/cacheEvict annotation type implementation

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedissonCacheConfiguration {


    /**
     * Property holder for holding the Redis cache configuration properties like
     * <code>Host, Port, Session Duration</code>, etc.
     * 
     * <p>
     * Bean with name <code>redisCacheConfigProperties</code> should be populated with these
     * configuration properties and then loaded in the application context.
     */
    @Autowired
    private RedissonConfigProperties redisCacheConfigProperties;

    /**
     * Sets the Redis cache configuration properties.
     * 
     * @param redisCacheConfigProperties Property holder for holding the Redis cache configuration
     *        properties.
     */
    public void setRedissonConfigProperties(
            final RedissonConfigProperties redisCacheConfigProperties) {
        this.redisCacheConfigProperties = redisCacheConfigProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {

        CacheManager cacheManager = new RedissonSpringCacheManager(redissonClient(), getCacheConfigs());
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Bean 
    public Map<String, CacheConfig> getCacheConfigs(){
        Map<String, CacheConfig> config = new HashMap<String, CacheConfig>();
        // ttl = 24 mins, maxIdleTime = 12 mins
        config.put("testCache", new CacheConfig(24*60*1000, 12*60*1000));
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedissonClient redissonClient() {
        Config config = new Config();
            SingleServerConfig singleServerConfig = config.useSingleServer();
            // format as redis://127.0.0.1:7181 or rediss://127.0.0.1:7181 for SSL
            String schema = redisCacheConfigProperties.isSsl() ? "rediss://" : "";
            singleServerConfig.setAddress(schema + redisCacheConfigProperties.getHost() + ":" + redisCacheConfigProperties.getPort());
            singleServerConfig.setDatabase(redisCacheConfigProperties.getDatabase());
            if (redisCacheConfigProperties.getPassword() != null) {
                singleServerConfig.setPassword(redisCacheConfigProperties.getPassword());
            }
        return Redisson.create(config);
    }
}
```

*Cachable Annotation Usage*

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "#cacheProperies.cacheName", key = "#cacheProperies.cacheKey", unless = "#result==null")
    public Object fetchData( final CacheProperties cacheProperies) {
        // If there is no cached data by the given key, then we will return NULL.
        return doTheOperation();
    }

    @CacheEvict(cacheNames = "#cacheProperies.cacheName", key = "#cacheProperies.cacheKey")
    public void removeData(final CacheProperties cacheProperies) {
        // Deletes the Cached CartInfo.
    }

    @CachePut(cacheNames = "#cacheProperies.cacheName", key = "#cacheProperies.cacheKey", unless = "#result==null")
    public Object cacheData(final Object object, final CacheProperties cacheProperies ) {
        // Returns the same  object which is received as parameter,
        // so that this  object will be cached by key '... reference'.
        return doTheOperation();
    }
```